# Is there a way to set an expiry date on tracking tags that run on your website, specifically when using google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Is there a way to set an expiry date on tracking tags that run on your website, specifically when using google tag manager?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to do this, but you can set it up without too much trouble. First set up a new *User-Defined Variable*, use the type "Custom Javascript" , and call it something helpful like "Date". Put the following script in as the value:

```
function () {
  var d = new Date();
  var y = d.getFullYear();
  var m = (d.getMonth() + 1 + '').padStart(2,0);
  var d = (d.getDate() + '').padStart(2,0);
  return y + m + d;
}
```

That will give you a variable which returns the date in a format like YYYYMMDD. So, for example, on February 14, 2007, it would return **20070214**.

Save that variable, and in the trigger that fires your tag, set a condition like [name of your variable] less than [desired date of expiration]. Along the lines of :

```
Date less than 20200603
```

With that, the tag will only fire if the date is *before* June 3, 2020.

You can use this same technique to only fire tags _after _ a certain date as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Tag Manager you can set a firing schedule for a tag under "Advanced Settings".

[image]

The limitation here is that you cannot use variables for dates (if you feel that actually somehow limits here).